# Sympy : Exp(-i.H.t) : Error Mutabledensematrix

Tags: python, sympy

This question follows this one ([Sympy : Exp(-i.H.t)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61460662/7462275)). I tried many stupid things to this first problem: No comment.

My real problem is the following :

```
t=sympy.Symbol('t')
H=sympy.Matrix([[3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1 , 2, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4]])
A = sympy.exp(-sympy.I * H * t)
```

I get this error : *TypeError: unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix'*

How can I solve it ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: The actual error message is "IndexError: list index out of range". Can you report that as a bug to sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19210

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin. Thanks a lot to open this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work but any way a workaround is to compute the exponential yourself from the Jordan form:

```
In [11]: P, J = H.jordan_form()                                                                                                                

In [12]: P*(-I*t*J).exp()*P.inv()                                                                                                              
Out[12]: 
⎡ -3⋅ⅈ⋅t                                                                                                                            ⎤
⎢ℯ                                       0                                                        0                             0   ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                   ⎥
⎢                       ⎛3   √17⎞                     ⎛3   √17⎞                        ⎛3   √17⎞                ⎛3   √17⎞           ⎥
⎢                  -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ + ───⎟                -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ - ───⎟                   -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ + ───⎟           -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ - ───⎟           ⎥
⎢                       ⎝2    2 ⎠                     ⎝2    2 ⎠                        ⎝2    2 ⎠                ⎝2    2 ⎠           ⎥
⎢           4⋅√17⋅ℯ                           2⋅ℯ                             16⋅ℯ                     16⋅ℯ                         ⎥
⎢   0     - ───────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────── - ──────────────────────     0   ⎥
⎢                  ⎛  √17   1⎞      ⎛  1   √17⎞ ⎛      2           2    ⎞              ⎛  √17   1⎞   ⎛  1   √17⎞                    ⎥
⎢               17⋅⎜- ─── - ─⎟      ⎜- ─ + ───⎟⋅⎜- ───────── + ─────────⎟  (-17 + √17)⋅⎜- ─── - ─⎟   ⎜- ─ + ───⎟⋅(√17 + 17)         ⎥
⎢                  ⎝   2    2⎠      ⎝  2    2 ⎠ ⎜    √17   1     1   √17⎟              ⎝   2    2⎠   ⎝  2    2 ⎠                    ⎥
⎢                                               ⎜  - ─── - ─   - ─ + ───⎟                                                           ⎥
⎢                                               ⎝     2    2     2    2 ⎠                                                           ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                   ⎥
⎢                             ⎛3   √17⎞             ⎛3   √17⎞                            ⎛3   √17⎞           ⎛3   √17⎞              ⎥
⎢                        -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ + ───⎟        -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ - ───⎟                       -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ + ───⎟      -ⅈ⋅t⋅⎜─ - ───⎟              ⎥
⎢                             ⎝2    2 ⎠             ⎝2    2 ⎠                            ⎝2    2 ⎠           ⎝2    2 ⎠              ⎥
⎢                 2⋅√17⋅ℯ                     ℯ                                  8⋅ℯ                 8⋅ℯ                            ⎥
⎢   0             ───────────────────── - ───────────────────────              - ───────────────── + ─────────────────          0   ⎥
⎢                           17                  2           2                        -17 + √17            √17 + 17                  ⎥
⎢                                         - ───────── + ─────────                                                                   ⎥
⎢                                             √17   1     1   √17                                                                   ⎥
⎢                                           - ─── - ─   - ─ + ───                                                                   ⎥
⎢                                              2    2     2    2                                                                    ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                   ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                             -4⋅ⅈ⋅t⎥
⎣   0                                    0                                                        0                          ℯ      ⎦
```